# CLOSED Type 'IMyClass[]' has no properties in common with type 'IMyClass' while concatenating http answer

Tags: angular, typescript

What I am trying to do is to concatenate many answers in one bind field to populate a select. This version of the code from component works fine:

```
getAllDevices(selectedVals: Array<any>) {
    if (selectedVals) {
        for (let i = 0; i < selectedVals.length; i++) {
            this.njdDataOwner = selectedVals[i];
            this.njdAllowedDeviceService.queryAvailableByDataOwner(
                this.njdDataOwner.id
            ).subscribe(
                (res: HttpResponse<INjdApiDevice[]>) => {
                    // when njdapidevices is newly populated it forces data refresh on html page
                    this.njdapidevices = (res.body);
                },
                (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
            );
        }
    }
```

}

The point is that it returns only the last response, so I changed it a bit to this form:

```
getAllDevices(selectedVals: Array<any>) {
    if (selectedVals) {
        for (let i = 0; i < selectedVals.length; i++) {
            this.njdDataOwner = selectedVals[i];
            this.njdAllowedDeviceService.queryAvailableByDataOwner(
                this.njdDataOwner.id
            ).subscribe(
                (res: HttpResponse<INjdApiDevice[]>) => {
                    // when njdapidevices is newly populated it forces data refresh on html page
                    this.njdapidevices.push(res.body);
                },
                (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
            );
        }
    }
```

}

to push each http resource to the array, but not matter any of my tries I (res.body) is red underlined with error "Type 'INjdApiDevice[]' has no properties in common with type 'INjdApiDevice'.
This is the NjdApiDevice model class:

```
export interface INjdApiDevice {
    Name?: string;
    Description?: string;
    CycleTime?: number;
    TagCount?: number;
    IsValid?: boolean;
    dataOwner?: number;
}

export class NjdApiDevice implements INjdApiDevice {
    constructor(
        public Name?: string,
        public Description?: string,
        public CycleTime?: number,
        public TagCount?: number,
        public IsValid?: boolean,
        public dataOwner?: number
    ) {}
}
```

but I can't really see where the problem is.

Comment: `Array.push` only accepts a single item, not an array. If you look at the line number associated with the TS error, you'll see it'll be `this.njdapidevices.push(res.body);`

Comment: @Wazner : ok, I realized it now, but how can I do that then? Should I read res.body as an array and for each item of it push that very same item to this.njdapidevices?

Comment: @Wazner : I tried to push every single item of res.body, but I get "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" on line "this.njdapidevices.push(res.body[i]);"

Comment: I made it! Despite the fact that apidevices is defined by "njdapidevices: INjdApiDevice[]; " line, I added a second initialization like this "this.njdapidevices = [];" before using it and know it works fine. I thought the first one was enough to have njdapidevices declared as an array but I was clearly wrong. I am going to close the question.